# What's the true purpose of setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically

Tags: javascript, android, webview

According to [Android document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(boolean)):

> Tells JavaScript to open windows automatically. This applies to the JavaScript function window.open(). The default is false.

But I didn't see any different between use or not use this API in my code, window.open works fine in the both cases, so what's the true purpose of this API or my usage is not correct?

My code sample as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView mWebView;
//private Context mContext
RelativeLayout mParent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mParent = new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.this);
    setContentView(mParent);

    mWebView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
    WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mParent.addView(mWebView);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/create_window.html");

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean dialog, boolean userGesture, Message resultMsg) {
            WebView newWebView = new WebView(view.getContext());
            newWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("BBB");
            //newWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            //newWebView.setWebChromeClient(this);
            newWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
            //view.getSettings().setUserAgentString("CCC");
            mParent.addView(newWebView);
            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(newWebView);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
            mParent.removeViewAt(mParent.getChildCount() - 1);
        }
    });

}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
}
```

}

The content of create_window.html as below:

```
<html>
<!-- scripts -->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Create Window</title>
    <script>
        function
        openURL ()
        {
            alert ("opening window");
            window.open ("http://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/",  "_blank", "width=200,height=100");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
  <button onclick="openURL()">open website in new window</button>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How did you do `window.open`? Usually it is blocked only when done outside of an event handler (such as onclick).

Comment: Yes, I don't think that will be blocked. Try calling `window.open` from a `setTimeout`. Then you can probably control whether that is allowed.

Comment: @Thilo Thanks a lot for your great help. I understand it now.